# Problems eliminating white space under footer

Tags: html, css, web, footer

I have been inspecting my footer in Firebug and can't seem to see the issue that is causing my footer to have white space under it.  If someone could take a quick look that would be great. Thanks!

www.jobspark.ca

```
#page-footer-wrapper {
border-top: 1px solid #e6e6e6;
background: #000;
color: #fff;
width: auto;
margin: 0;
}
```

**Update**
So the answer that I accepted below has fixed the issue in all browsers except when I view in IE 9. What do I need to add to the css so it works with IE.

Comment: Yeah, IE9 has some kind of JS going on that overrides the clearfix styles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the clearfix method I use these days:

```
header:after,
section:after,
article:after,
footer:after,
#navigation-top:after,
#navigation-bottom:after,
#page-header-wrapper:after,
#banner-area-wrapper:after,
#page-body-wrapper:after,
#page-footer-wrapper:after,
.clearer:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: thanks this worked but when I viewed in IE still has white gap. Do I need to add something to this css to help with IE. I viewed with IE9

Comment: Unfortunately, some kind of JavaScript on your page is disabling the styles in IE9. If you turn off JS in IE9, the code works.

Comment: oh I see. I only have a few lines of JavaScript but will check if they are needed or not. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your clear, the `height:0;` property.

```
header:after, section:after, article:after, footer:after, #navigationtop:after, #navigation-bottom:after, #page-header-wrapper:after, #banner-area-wrapper:after, #page-body-wrapper:after, #page-footer-wrapper:after, .clearer:after {
clear: both;
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Ok thanks for finding that. What do I need to do with the Height:0;

Comment: See the other answer, basically use a different clearfix method.

Answer (score 1):

you add the font-size:0, like this:

```
header:after, section:after, article:after, footer:after, #navigation-top:after, #navigation-bottom:after, #page-header-wrapper:after, #banner-area-wrapper:after, #page-body-wrapper:after, #page-footer-wrapper:after, .clearer:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
**font-size: 0;**
}
```

[image]

Comment: you are welcome, You should have more know about the principle and method of removal of floating。 (^_^)

Answer (score 0):

Problem here：

```
header:after, section:after, article:after, footer:after, #navigation-top:after, #navigation-bottom:after, #page-header-wrapper:after, #banner-area-wrapper:after, #page-body-wrapper:after, #page-footer-wrapper:after, .clearer:after {
content: ".";
display: block;
height: 0;
clear: both;
visibility: hidden;
}
```

you will add font-size:0 to fix the bug. and you will another clear float method:

```
.clearfix:before,
.clearfix:after {
   content:"";
   display: table;
}
.clearfix:after{
  clear:both;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.clearfix{
  zoom: 1;/*for ie6*/
}
```

If you want to know the method, please click here：[clear float](http://www.w3cplus.com/css/clear-float)

Comment: Sorry I cant get it to work... can you clear your answer again and just reinsert the css I need to add. Thanks